# I want to prevent Duplicate entry in webform uri?

Tags: 7, webforms, files, users

I have a webform but when user's are uploading the file in webform they are getting "Error: The website is encounter an unexpected error"

when i check the dblog i came to know that the error:PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://webform/My filename_5.docx' for key 'uri':

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://webform/My Story_5.docx' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (uid, filename, uri, filemime, filesize, status, timestamp, type) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 333485 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => My Story.docx [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => public://webform/My Story_5.docx [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 12070 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1426586544 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => default ) in drupal_write_record()




function drupal_write_record($table, &$record, $primary_keys = array()) {
  // Standardize $primary_keys to an array.
  if (is_string($primary_keys)) {
    $primary_keys = array($primary_keys);
  }

  $schema = drupal_get_schema($table);
  if (empty($schema)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $object = (object) $record;
  $fields = array();

  // Go through the schema to determine fields to write.
  foreach ($schema['fields'] as $field => $info) {
    if ($info['type'] == 'serial') {
      // Skip serial types if we are updating.
      if (!empty($primary_keys)) {
        continue;
      }
      // Track serial field so we can helpfully populate them after the query.
      // NOTE: Each table should come with one serial field only.
      $serial = $field;
    }

    // Skip field if it is in $primary_keys as it is unnecessary to update a
    // field to the value it is already set to.
    if (in_array($field, $primary_keys)) {
      continue;
    }

    if (!property_exists($object, $field)) {
      // Skip fields that are not provided, default values are already known
      // by the database.
      continue;
    }

    // Build array of fields to update or insert.
    if (empty($info['serialize'])) {
      $fields[$field] = $object->$field;
    }
    else {
      $fields[$field] = serialize($object->$field);
    }

    // Type cast to proper datatype, except when the value is NULL and the
    // column allows this.
    //
    // MySQL PDO silently casts e.g. FALSE and '' to 0 when inserting the value
    // into an integer column, but PostgreSQL PDO does not. Also type cast NULL
    // when the column does not allow this.
    if (isset($object->$field) || !empty($info['not null'])) {
      if ($info['type'] == 'int' || $info['type'] == 'serial') {
        $fields[$field] = (int) $fields[$field];
      }
      elseif ($info['type'] == 'float') {
        $fields[$field] = (float) $fields[$field];
      }
      else {
        $fields[$field] = (string) $fields[$field];
      }
    }
  }

  if (empty($fields)) {
    return;
  }

  // Build the SQL.
  if (empty($primary_keys)) {
    // We are doing an insert.
    $options = array('return' => Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID);
    if (isset($serial) && isset($fields[$serial])) {
      // If the serial column has been explicitly set with an ID, then we don't
      // require the database to return the last insert id.
      if ($fields[$serial]) {
        $options['return'] = Database::RETURN_AFFECTED;
      }
      // If a serial column does exist with no value (i.e. 0) then remove it as
      // the database will insert the correct value for us.
      else {
        unset($fields[$serial]);
      }
    }
    $query = db_insert($table, $options)->fields($fields);
    $return = SAVED_NEW;
  }
  else {
    $query = db_update($table)->fields($fields);
    foreach ($primary_keys as $key) {
      $query->condition($key, $object->$key);
    }
    $return = SAVED_UPDATED;
  }

  // Execute the SQL.
  if ($query_return = $query->execute()) {
    if (isset($serial)) {
      // If the database was not told to return the last insert id, it will be
      // because we already know it.
      if (isset($options) && $options['return'] != Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID) {
        $object->$serial = $fields[$serial];
      }
      else {
        $object->$serial = $query_return;
      }
    }
  }
  // If we have a single-field primary key but got no insert ID, the
  // query failed. Note that we explicitly check for FALSE, because
  // a valid update query which doesn't change any values will return
  // zero (0) affected rows.
  elseif ($query_return === FALSE && count($primary_keys) == 1) {
    $return = FALSE;
  }

  // If we are inserting, populate empty fields with default values.
  if (empty($primary_keys)) {
    foreach ($schema['fields'] as $field => $info) {
      if (isset($info['default']) && !property_exists($object, $field)) {
        $object->$field = $info['default'];
      }
    }
  }

  // If we began with an array, convert back.
  if (is_array($record)) {
    $record = (array) $object;
  }

  return $return;
}
```

So how can we prevent duplication of files.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan filename_0 is not happening this is the issue please help me to resolve this

Comment: I've tested this on my local. It's working fine here. Which version of webform are you using? It seems module bug.

Comment: i am using webform Version 2, June 1991 and this error is coming again what should i do please help me

Comment: Is the error present when you upload a file with another name? If yes the problem is a previous faulty upload.

Comment: @NikhilAnant It's quite unlikely you're using a module from 1991, given that Drupal didn't exist until 10 years later. If you don't have the very latest version of Webform installed, make sure you install that. After that you might need to open a bug report

Comment: @Clive can we do anything to resolve this because i cant install latest webform

Comment: i am using version = "7.x-3.15"
core = "7.x"
project = "webform"

Comment: Its a bug in webform i suppose

Comment: Can you please help me user is uploading file with name My Story.docx the file is uploading but showing the message "Error: The website is encounter an unexpected error"

Comment: I have update the module but still its the same problem